# How to display Bet Calculator result on my html page with code created in JavaScript language

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function betCalculator(points, numberOfTeams) {

    var odds;
    var numberOfTeams = +prompt("Enter No of Teams");
    var betAmount = +prompt("Enter Bet Amount");  
     

    switch(true) {
    
    // 2 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (5 / 6);
      break;

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (10 / 13);
      break;

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (5 / 7);
      break;

    // 3 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (8 / 5);
      break;

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (7 / 5);
      break;

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (13 / 10);
      break;

    // 4 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (14 / 5);
      break;

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (5 / 2);
      break;

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (2 / 1);
      break;

    // 5 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (9 / 2);
      break;

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (4 / 1);
      break;
     
case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (3 / 1);
      break;

    // 6 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (7 / 1);
      break;

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (11 / 2);
      break;

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (5 / 1);
      break;

default:
    return ("You are out of the allowed betting rules and range for this type of bet!");
}

return parseFloat((odds * betAmount + betAmount) .toFixed(2));

}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Save").onclick = function fun() {
        alert(betCalculator(+prompt("Enter Points")));
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>NFL Teaser Bet Calculator</title>
<script src="nflteaserbet.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<h2>ProFootball (NFL) Teaser Bet</h2>

<button id="Save" onclick="fun();">Calculate Payout</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
// NFL Teaser Bet Payout

function betCalculator(points, numberOfTeams) {

    var odds;
    var numberOfTeams = +prompt("Enter No of Teams");
    var betAmount = +prompt("Enter Bet Amount");  
    
    // 2 Teams Bet

    switch(true) {

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (5 / 6);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (10 / 13);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (5 / 7);
    break;

    // 3 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (8 / 5);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (7 / 5);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (13 / 10);
    break;

    // 4 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (14 / 5);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (5 / 2);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (2 / 1);
    break;

    // 5 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (9 / 2);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (4 / 1);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (3 / 1);
    break;

    // 6 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (7 / 1);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (11 / 2);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (5 / 1);
    break;

default:
    return ("You are out of the allowed betting rules and range for this type of bet!");
}

return parseFloat((odds * betAmount + betAmount) .toFixed(2));

}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Save").onclick = function fun() {
        alert(betCalculator(+prompt("Enter Points")));
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>NFL Teaser Bet Calculator</title>
<script src="nflteaserbet.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<h2>ProFootball (NFL) Teaser Bet</h2>

<button id="Save" onclick="fun();">Calculate Payout</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am currently using the following JavaScript code to calculate NFL Teaser bets Payouts.
From my index page, I have placed the code `<button id="Save" onclick="fun();">Calculate Payout</button>` which allows me to open a popup page once clicked on it and enter the requested data to be calculated.

My desire is to place a form in my index page from where I can enter the same numbers and get the result within the form instead of a popup form.

I know how I can create the form in my index page, but I don't know how to integrate it with JavaScript code and have the results on the form.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function betCalculator(points, numberOfTeams) {

    var odds;
    var numberOfTeams = +prompt("Enter No of Teams");
    var betAmount = +prompt("Enter Bet Amount");  

    // 2 Teams Bet

    switch(true) {

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (5 / 6);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (10 / 13);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 2)):
    odds = (5 / 7);
    break;

    // 3 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (8 / 5);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (7 / 5);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 3)):
    odds = (13 / 10);
    break;

    // 4 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (14 / 5);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (5 / 2);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 4)):
    odds = (2 / 1);
    break;

    // 5 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (9 / 2);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (4 / 1);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 5)):
    odds = (3 / 1);
    break;

    // 6 Teams Bet

case ((points === 6) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (7 / 1);

case ((points === 6.5) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (11 / 2);

case ((points === 7) && (numberOfTeams === 6)):
    odds = (5 / 1);
    break;

default:
    return ("You are out of the allowed betting rules and range for this type of bet!");
}

return parseFloat((odds * betAmount + betAmount) .toFixed(2));

}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Save").onclick = function fun() {
        alert(betCalculator(+prompt("Enter Points")));
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to learn how to manipualte the DOM with javascript. You are already doing there by assigning an event to the Save button.

Comment: With `document.getElementById()` you can reference any HTML element in the document. Get values, set values in them, whatever you can think of.

Comment: Try changing your onsubmit to just `function () {betCalculator();}` and putting the display functionality in you betCalculator function.

Comment: Below is the opening for the script:  `document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
   var result = betCalculator();
   document.getElementById('betCalculator').innerHTML = result;
    return false;
};

    function betCalculator()
    {
      var points = document.getElementById("points").value;
      var numberOfTeams = document.getElementById("numberOfTeams").value;
      var betAmount = document.getElementById("betAmount").value;
      var odds;`

Comment: Hello Sydney,  the following is the code I use to calculate the payout and I don't see it in your suggestion. `return parseFloat((odds * betAmount + betAmount) .toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your odds to an object, which contains more objects. For me this is easier to read and maintain. We then can also pull the odds directly from this object using our form values to access the appropriate properties of the object.

I've used Radio Buttons to restrict the user to values we accept. I've also added some basic validation and error handling.

Finally we update a DOM element once the calculation is complete.

```js
// NFL Teaser Bet Payout

function betCalculator() {
    //Set up our odds in an obect, easier to read and maintain
    const oddsData = {
      "2Teams" : {"6" : (5/6) , "6.5" : (10/13), "7" : (5/7)},
      "3Teams" : {"6" : (8/5) , "6.5" : (7/5)  , "7" : (13/10)},
      "4Teams" : {"6" : (14/5), "6.5" : (5/2)  , "7" : (2/1)},
      "5Teams" : {"6" : (9/2) , "6.5" : (4/1)  , "7" : (3/1)},
      "6Teams" : {"6" : (7/1) , "6.5" : (11/2) , "7" : (5/1)}      
    }
    //Get value of selected teams radio, display error if none selected
    let selectedTeams = document.querySelector("[name=NumTeams]:checked");
    document.getElementById("teamsError").style.display = selectedTeams == null ? "block" : "none";
    
    //Get value of selected teams radio, display error if none selected
    let selectedPoints = document.querySelector("[name=Points]:checked");
    document.getElementById("pointsError").style.display = selectedPoints == null ? "block" : "none";
    
    let bet = 0; 
    if(document.getElementById("bet").value != "") {
      bet = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bet").value);
    }
    
    //Display error if no bet
    document.getElementById("betError").style.display = document.getElementById("bet").value == "" ? "block" : "none";
    
    let odds = 0;
    //Get odds from our object
    if(selectedTeams && selectedPoints) {           
       odds = oddsData[selectedTeams.value + "Teams"][selectedPoints.value];
    }
    
    //Display the result
    document.querySelector("#result > span").textContent = (odds * bet + bet).toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
.error {color:red; display:none;}
```

```html
<h2>ProFootball (NFL) Teaser Bet</h2>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Number of Teams</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="NumTeams" id="2Teams" value="2" /> 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="NumTeams" id="3Teams" value="3" /> 3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="NumTeams" id="4Teams" value="4" /> 4</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="NumTeams" id="5Teams" value="5" /> 5</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="NumTeams" id="6Teams" value="6" /> 6</label>
  <div id="teamsError" class="error">Please select Number of Teams</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Points</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Points" value="6" /> 6</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Points" value="6.5" /> 6.5</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Points" value="7" /> 7</label>
  <div id="pointsError" class="error">Please select Points</div>
</fieldset>
<label for="bet">Bet Amount</label> <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" id="bet" required>
<div id="betError" class="error">Please enter a bet</div>
<button id="Save" onclick="betCalculator();">Calculate Payout</button>
<div id="result">Payout: $<span></span></div>
```

Comment: Nice. It works the way I thought it should. I really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I have another question: Where in the JavaScript code I suppose to place the code. `error {color:red; display:none;}` ? Thanks.

Comment: That's actually a bit of CSS so it should go in a `<style>` block or `.css` file.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that. Thanks.

Comment: I have another question at [How to create a Sports Bet Calculator using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100701/how-to-create-a-sports-bet-calculator-using-javascript) that I would like to have a help if possible. It is a parlay calculator that I am trying to create. Please take a look at it if you can. Your recommendation is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

something like that ?

```js
const myForm= document.getElementById("my-form")
    , Points=        [ '6.0' ,  '6.5',  '7.0' ] 
    , TeamsN= { '2': [  5/ 6 ,  10/13 ,  5/ 7 ]
              , '3': [  8/ 5 ,   7/ 5 , 13/10 ]
              , '4': [ 14/ 5 ,   5/ 2 ,  2/ 1 ]
              , '5': [  9/ 2 ,  10/13 ,  5/ 7 ]
              , '6': [  5/ 6 ,  10/13 ,  5/ 7 ]
              }; 
let onSelect = true
Points.forEach((pt,n)=>{
  myForm.Points.add(new Option(` - ${pt} - `, n, onSelect, onSelect))
  onSelect = false
  });
onSelect = true
Object.keys(TeamsN).forEach(Tm=>{
  myForm.numberOfTeams.add(new Option(` - ${Tm} - `, Tm, onSelect, onSelect))
  onSelect = false
  });
myForm.onsubmit = e=>e.preventDefault()  // disable form submit
  ;
myForm.oninput = betCalculator
  ;
myForm.betAmount.onchange=_=> myForm.betAmount.value = parseFloat(myForm.betAmount.value).toFixed(2)
  ;
function betCalculator()
  {
  let bet  = myForm.betAmount.valueAsNumber
    , odds = TeamsN[myForm.numberOfTeams.value][myForm.Points.value]
    ;
  myForm.result.value = '$ '+((bet * odds) + bet).toFixed(2) 
  }
myForm.reset()
betCalculator()
```

```css
h2 { width: 22em; text-align: center;}
fieldset { margin-top: 1em; width: 15em; float: left; display: block;}
fieldset:nth-of-type(3),
fieldset:nth-of-type(4) { clear: both; width: 32em }
select { width: 7em; margin-left: 2em; }
output { font-weight: bold; float: right; font-size: 1.2em; }
```

```html
<h2>ProFootball (NFL) Teaser Bet </h2>
<form action="" id="my-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Points :</legend>
    <select name="Points"></select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Number Of Teams:</legend>
    <select name="numberOfTeams" ></select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Bet amount :</legend>
    <input type="number" name="betAmount" step="10" min=0 value="0">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>result</legend>
    <output name="result" value="0"></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes. It works just the way it should. I really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello Mister Jojo. I am trying to use the way you have it but this time to calculate Parlay Bet Payout with Teams starting from 1 to 8 or 10 and with either positive or negative moneyLine. Something like: `if ((numberOfTeams === 1) && (moneyLine >= 0)) {
            odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine1)) + 1;`. Would it be possible to program it by object, just the way you have it?

Comment: Thanks @Mister Jojo

Comment: Hello @Mister Jojo. Global Parlay Payout calculation is quite different from Teaser or Fixed Odds calculation. So if I say: `if ((numberOfTeams === 1) && (moneyLine1 >= 0)) { odds1 = moneyLine1 >= 0 ? (moneyLine1/ 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine1)) + 1;` But because it has more than just one moneyLine, I would need to calculate the value for odds2 ... odds5 and so on, which would be `if ((numberOfTeams === 2) && (moneyLine2 >= 0)) { odds2 = moneyLine2 >= 0 ? (moneyLine2/ 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine2)) + 1;` . and then the Payout would be equal to odds1*odds2...odds5*betAmount

Comment: Good job. Very creative. I like it. But what I meant was if it was possible to apply that same way for Global Parlay Payout seeing that for Global Parlay Payout, the formulas are different.  You would need to use a combined formula to be able to accept negative or positive money line like what is shown here:  `if ((numberOfTeams === 1) && (moneyLine1 >= 0)) { odds1 = moneyLine1 >= 0 ? (moneyLine1/ 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine1)) + 1; `

Comment: Hello @Mister Jojo. Here is the code I use for  `// Single Straight Bet Calculator

function betCalculator(moneyLine) {
    var odds;
    var betAmount = +prompt("Enter Bet Amount");    

if (moneyLine >= 0) { 
    odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1;


} else {
    odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1;
     
} 
return parseFloat((odds * betAmount).toFixed(2));
}
alert(betCalculator(+prompt("Enter Money Line"))); `. I am trying to create one that can accept more than one money line.

Comment: Sure. Soon will do it. Thanks

Comment: just posted the question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100701/how-to-create-a-sports-bet-calculator-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you put your html form on the page, you can have a button with the type "submit".  Html forms have an "onsubmit" event built in.  The event holds the names and values of the fields.  The default action is a http request which results in loading a new page.  Define your own submit event handler and use the event method 'preventDefault()' which will stop the http request.  Then you can take names and values from the event object to calculate your results.

(Edited to use OP's html)

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="myEventHandler()" >
 <table border = "0" width = "300">
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Enter Points:</td>
     <td><input type="text" id="points" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Number Of Teams:</td>
     <td><input type="text" id="teams" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Bet Amount:</td>
     <td><input type="text" id="bet" /></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <button type="calculate">Calculate</button>
 <button type="reset">Clear</button>
</form>
<script>
  function myEventHandler(eventObject) {
    eventObject.preventDefault();
    let fieldIds = ['points', 'teams', 'bet'];
    let input = {};
    for (let i=0; i < fieldIds.length; i++) {
      let key = fieldIds[i];
      let value = eventObject.target.getElementById(fieldIds[i]).value;
      input[key] = value;
    };
    betCalculator(input.points, input.teams, input.bet);
  }
</script>
```

prevent default: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

event object: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_event.asp

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the following code but still not working:

Comment: Using that form: `<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <table  border = "0" width = "300">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Enter Points:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="points" /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Number Of Teams:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="teams" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Bet Amount:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="bet" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <button type="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <button type="reset">Clear</button>
</form>`

Comment: Tried it but the form disappears after clicking calculate button.

Comment: You see, the code is working when opening on a popup. You can see it if you run code snipped.