# How to create a Sports Bet Calculator using javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have created this simple straight bet calculator using JavaScript. 
It allows me to calculate, if it is a winning ticket, how much the payout will be.

How it works?
First I will enter the moneyLine number, which can be mostly any 3 digits number and I then enter the bet amount.

Now, the moneyLine can either be negative (-) if betting a favorite or positive (+) if betting the underdog.

Please see the code below:
For testing proposes, I use any -110 or 110 and then, any bet amount. But it can actually be any chosen moneyLine and betAmount.

```
// Single Straight Sports Bet Calculator 

function betCalculator(moneyLine) { 

    var odds;
    var betAmount = +prompt("Enter Bet Amount"); 

    if (moneyLine >= 0) { 
        odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1; 

    } else  {
        odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1; 


    } return ((odds * betAmount).toFixed(2)); 
}
 alert(betCalculator(+prompt("Enter Money Line")));
```

```js
// Single Straight Sports Bet Calculator 

function betCalculator(moneyLine) { 
    
    var odds;
    var betAmount = +prompt("Enter Bet Amount"); 
    
    if (moneyLine >= 0) { 
        odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1; 
    
    } else  {
        odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1; 
    

    } return ((odds * betAmount).toFixed(2)); 
}
 alert(betCalculator(+prompt("Enter Money Line")));
```

And here is what I would like to have accomplished.
My desire is to create a Parlay Calculator, using the above formulas, that will allow me to enter one bet amount and several money lines, instead of just one.

A parlay is a single bet that links together two or more individual wagers for a high payout. So a parlay ticket can have two or more teams on it.

What I would also like to do is to be able to enter those numbers (moneyLine and betAmount) on a form instead of a popup window.

I tried doing it myself with no avail. Somehow, it is not showing the result.

```js
// True Odds Parlay Bets
  
const myForm= document.getElementById("my-form")

var odds;
var moneyLine

  , trueOdds=
      { 'moneyLine1 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      , 'moneyLine2 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      , 'moneyLine3 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      , 'moneyLine4 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      , 'moneyLine5 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      , 'moneyLine6 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      , 'moneyLine7 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      , 'moneyLine8 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      , 'moneyLine9 >= 0': (odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1)
      };
myForm.onsubmit = e=>e.preventDefault();  // disable form submit
myForm.oninput = betCalculator;

function betCalculator() {
    let bet  = myForm.betAmount.valueAsNumber, odds = trueOdds[(myForm.moneyLine1.value + '_' + myForm.moneyLine2.value + '_' + myForm.moneyLine3.value + '_' + myForm.moneyLine4.value + '_' + myForm.moneyLine5.value + '_' + myForm.moneyLine6.value + '_' + myForm.moneyLine7.value + '_' + myForm.moneyLine8.value + '_' + myForm.moneyLine9.value)];

 

// This code is used to get rid of "NaN"
if ( isNaN(bet) || isNaN(odds) ) {
  return 0;
}

myForm.result.value = '" ' + '$ '+(odds * bet).toFixed(2) + ' "'
}
betCalculator()
```

```css
fieldset { margin-top: 1em;}
 label { display: inline-block; width: 6em; }
 input[type="radio"] {
   -webkit-appearance: checkbox; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-appearance: checkbox;    /* Firefox */
   -ms-appearance: checkbox;
   }
```

```html
<head>
<title>True Odds Parlay Bet Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="trueoddstyle.css">


</head>
<body>

<h2>True Odds Parlay Bet Calculator</h2>

<p>
  Useful for both <b>Negative "-"</b> and/or <b>Positive "+"</b> Money Lines including Single Straight Bets!
</p>

<form action="" id="my-form">
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Bet Amount :</legend>
    <input type="number" name="betAmount" step=any min=0>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Team Respective Money Line :</legend>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine1" step=any min=0>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine2" step=any min=0>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine3" step=any min=0>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine4" step=any min=0>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine5" step=any min=0>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine6" step=any min=0>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine7" step=any min=0>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine8" step=any min=0>
    <input type="number" name="moneyLine9" step=any min=0>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Payout :</legend>
    <output name="result" value=''></output>

    <br><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Calculator!"</input>
  </fieldset>
</form>


</body>
```

Please see the snippet code for details.
Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: So you want an interactive app that allows people to put in these numbers and does the calculations for them? Learn react, or jquery, or vue

Comment: @TKol. Thanks. But I know there are people out there who can do it with JavaScript. I just want to learn from them.

Comment: That's fine, you don't need to use react or jquery or vue, but you will definitely need to figure out something because your question here is too general. You're not going to get an answer to your question, because an answer to your question is an entire lecture on how to make user interfaces with javascript. You don't need a stackoverflow answer for your question, you need a book.

Comment: @TKoL, I have created similar calculator at [True Odds Parlay Calculator based on Global Sportsbook Odds!](https://eagleproweb.com/calculators/parlay-calculator) using simple forms and formulas. I just want to do something similar in JavaScript

Comment: See my revised first version :)

Comment: Yes.Really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised first version :)

```js
const bt_Nwline = document.getElementById('New-Line')
  ,   xForm     = document.getElementById('form-X')
  ,   wTable    = xForm.querySelector('table')
  ,   baseLine  = wTable.querySelector('thead tr:nth-of-type(3)')
  ,   tBody     = wTable.querySelector('tbody')
  ,   tPayout   = wTable.querySelector('tfoot td:nth-of-type(2)')
  ;
xForm.onsubmit = e=>e.preventDefault()  // disable form submit
  ;
xForm.onreset =_=>{ tPayout.textContent = '0.00' }
  ;
function betCalculator()
  {
  let bet  = xForm.betAmount.valueAsNumber || 0
    , odds = [...tBody.querySelectorAll('input')]
              .filter(ml=>!isNaN(ml.valueAsNumber) )
              .reduce((odd,ml)=> odd *= ml.valueAsNumber >= 0
                                      ? (ml.valueAsNumber /100) +1
                                      : (100 / Math.abs(ml.valueAsNumber)) +1
                    ,1)
  tPayout.textContent = ((odds *bet).toFixed(2)).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,',')
  }
betCalculator()
  ;
bt_Nwline.onclick=_=>
  {
  tBody.appendChild( baseLine.cloneNode(true)) 
  }
tBody.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return
  wTable.deleteRow(e.target.closest('tr').rowIndex)
  betCalculator()
  }
xForm.oninput = betCalculator
  ;
```

```css
table   { border-collapse: collapse; }
caption { background-color: #1a4641; color: whitesmoke; font-weight: bold;  padding: .6em;}
td:nth-of-type(1) { min-width:8em; }
td      { border: 1px solid grey; padding: .4em .8em; }
thead   { background-color: #7adfd3; color: #1d1313;  font-weight: bold; }

thead tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1) { text-align: right; }
thead tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(1) { text-align: center; }

thead tr:nth-of-type(3) { display: none; counter-reset: line; }
tbody tr { counter-increment: line; }
tbody td:nth-of-type(1) {  color: darkslategrey; }
tbody td:nth-of-type(1)::before { content: counter(line) '\00a0-\00a0\00a0'; }

tfoot { font-weight: bold; }
tfoot td:nth-of-type(1) { text-align: right; }
tfoot td:nth-of-type(2)::before { content: '$ ' }

input { font-size: 1.2em; text-align: right; direction: rtl; width:8em;}

button  { 
  width: 2em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border-radius: 1em / .6em;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: .8em;
  padding: 0;
}
thead tr:nth-of-type(1) button { background-color: #063329; }
thead tr:nth-of-type(2) button { background-color: crimson; }
tbody button  { background-color: #071b3f;}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form-X">
  <table>
    <caption title="Useful for both Negative ‘−’ and / or Positive ‘+’ Money Lines including Single Straight Bets!">
      True Odds Parlay Bet Calculator
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Bet Amount : </td>
        <td><input type="number" step="10" value="0" name="betAmount" min="0"></td>
        <td><button type="reset">&empty;</button></td>   
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2">Teams Money Lines</td>  <td><button id="New-Line">+</button></td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable spellcheck="false">...</td>
        <td><input type="number" step="10" value="0"></td>
        <td><button>&#8722;</button></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td> Payout : </td>
        <td colspan="2"> </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>
```

After looking your second Snippet I do that:

```js
const myForm     = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   moneyLines = [...myForm.querySelectorAll('.moneyLine')]
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = e=>e.preventDefault()  // disable form submit
  ; 
myForm.oninput = betCalculator
  ;
function betCalculator()
  {
  let bet  = myForm.betAmount.valueAsNumber || 0
    , odds = moneyLines
                .filter(ml=>!isNaN(ml.valueAsNumber) )
                .reduce((odd,ml)=> odd *= ml.valueAsNumber >= 0
                                        ? (ml.valueAsNumber /100) +1
                                        : (100 / Math.abs(ml.valueAsNumber)) +1
                      ,1)

  
  myForm.result.value = (odds *bet).toFixed(2)
  }
betCalculator()
```

```css
form#my-form { position: relative; }
legend {font-size: .9em; }
legend:after { content: '\00a0' }
fieldset { display:block; width: 16em; position: absolute; }
fieldset:nth-child(1){ top: 1em; left: 1em; }
fieldset:nth-child(2){ top: 1em; left:20em; }
fieldset:nth-child(3){ top:19em; left: 1em; }
label   { display: block; float: left; clear: both; margin: .2em 1em .4em 0;}
label b { display: inline-block; width:2em }
label b::after { content:' : '}
label input { font-size: 1.2em; text-align: right; direction: rtl; width:8em;}
output { font-weight: bold; width: 14em; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey; display: block; margin: .8em; float: right; text-align: right;}
output::before {  content: '$ '; }
```

```html
<h2>True Odds Parlay Bet Calculator</h2>

<p><small>
  Useful for both <b>Negative "&#8722;"</b> and/or <b>Positive "+"</b> Money Lines including Single Straight Bets!
</small></p>

<form action="" id="my-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Bet Amount :</legend>
    <label><input type="number" name="betAmount" step=any min=0></label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Team Respective Money Lines :</legend>
    <label><b>1</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
    <label><b>2</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
    <label><b>3</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
    <label><b>4</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
    <label><b>5</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
    <label><b>6</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
    <label><b>7</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
    <label><b>8</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
    <label><b>9</b><input type="number" class="moneyLine" step=any ></label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Payout :</legend>
    <output name="result" value='0'></output>

    <br><br>
    <button type="reset">Reset Calculator!</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```